# In finite dimensional normed space, every convex set contains a basis

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I've been reading Lemma 5.60 here: http://epge.fgv.br/we/MD/TeoriaEconomicaAvancadaI/2009?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Aliprantis-Infinite-Dimensional-Analysis.pdf
(p.g 200, =217 on the pdf)

And couldn't understand the very beggining of the proof. Why such basis should exist?

Also, if anyone knows a nicer proof for this lemma i'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Please don't mistake internal to be interior.
The definition of internal points is in the top of the page.

Comment: That particular claim looks false. For instance $\{0\}$ is a perfectly valid convex set...

Comment: mm correct, then let's change it to non-trivial convex set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is acting in a sloppy way. It should say, "Let $C$ be a convex set *containing at least one internal point*" (if it contains no internal points, the implication is vacuous). Then, the fact that such a $C$ contains a basis is simple! Choose an internal $c\in C$. Then, for some $\alpha$, the vectors $c+\alpha e_i\in C$ for a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. So it is then clear that $C$ contains a basis.

Comment: Thanks man. I did feel like something here isn't quite true. Could you tell me if you feel like something else in this proof is too sloppy, so I might find myself wasting time understanding?

Comment: The rest of that proof looks fine - though not very elegant at all. You can just note that the points $c\pm \alpha e_i$ are in $C$. The convex hull of this is a "diamond" of sorts, centered at $c$ (i.e. it's a line segment in $1$ dimension, a square in $2$ dimensions, an octahedron in $3$ dimensions) and, obviously, $c$ is interior to that shape and since that shape is contained in $C$, it follows that $c$ is in the interior of $C$.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming that I did prove it in case the norm is $\|\cdot\|_1$, how would I generalize it to any norm?

Comment: @Functional Notice that the set of $v$ such that $\|v\|<\alpha$ can always be contained within a sphere in the usual metric, and that the convex closure of $c\pm \alpha e_i$ contains a sphere - ergo, if we scale the former down enough, it will fit in the latter. (More generally, any pair of norms in finite dimensions have $\frac{n_1(v)}{n_2(v)}$ bounded away from $0$, which is sufficient as well)